# Shriveling lilac blooms

Tags: lilac

Tall lilac about 10' was doing fine starting to bloom. We put new top soil, sprinkled alyssum seeds on top of lilac root area and put brick border and black rubber soil guard around same area. Now the lilac leaves and baby blooms are shriveling and dying. How can we keep it from totally dying?

Comment: When did you plant the lilac? What part of the world are you in, and can you add a photo showing the tree and the brick border please

Comment: Depending on how you did it, black rubber is a great way to raise soil temperature and restrict water flow.